# The Sound Card is Working, but not with MIDI

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I bought a sound card recently. I can get sound of the computer, except when I plug in the MIDI connection. My goal is to connect with Zynaddsubfx. Here are some screenshots of my settings on Qjackctl.

[image: Jack_Settings]
[image: Alsa]
[image: Audio]

And here are some volume settings.

[image: Volume]
I know that pnp is the setting I want because it doesn't show when it's unplugged. I did find one thing curious. Here is another screenshot of qjacktl.

[image: MIDI]

As you can see from the picture above, there is a MIDI setting too. I am sure that somehow it has something to do with jack. I would appreciate any help or feedback, thank you very much.

Comment: That sound card does not support MIDI. If you want to route the output of ZynAddSubFX to it, you have to configure Jack correctly.  (The device name shown is the last word of the sound card name.)

Comment: @CL, thank you for your comment. That's disappointing news but I think it's an honest answer. I did have one follow up question for you. The reason I got the sound card was because I thought it would help keep the real time audio down if I had an external sound card. My question: Is a MIDI interface considered a sound card? If you post your original comment in an answer I will vote for your question. – BJsgoodlife 16 mins ago

Comment: Yes, a MIDI interface (like your Uno) is also considered a sound card. Anyway, nowadays, no sound device supports MIDI unless it is explicitly advertised.